# Link CheckBox with Checkable Interface for a ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, custom-adapter

For my Android application I have implemented a `ListView` that is populated by a Custom Adapter from `BaseAdapter` and a custom Layout for the rows.

Now i would like to make entries checkable by using the corresponding methods from ListView, like `setItemChecked()` or `getCheckedItemCount()`.

I created a custom Layout class for the row layout that imlpements `Checkable` interface and retrieved the Button using `findViewById` to be able to access it inside the overridden methods from `Checkable`.

When long clicking on an entry in the list, the methods get invoked, but I get a NullpointerException, saying the CheckBox is referencing null:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

What is the appropriate way to link the checkbox of each entry inside a checkable Layout?

The checkable Layout class looks like this:

```java
package com.lastname.name.arcadaobjecttracker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


//extend the Layout for the row view (each element in the listView) to add support for checkable rows (called by the listView methods like setItemChecked() etc.)
public class CheckableRowLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable
{

    View view;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    public CheckableRowLayout(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CheckableRowLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CheckableRowLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }


    private void init(Context context)
    {
        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked)
    {
        checkBox.setChecked(checked);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked()
    {
        return checkBox.isChecked();
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle()
    {
        checkBox.toggle();
    }
}
```

The Layout consists of the following xml file with checkbox:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.lastname.name.arcadaobjecttracker.CheckableRowLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/list_view_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.lastname.name.arcadaobjecttracker.CheckableRowLayout>
```

which includes the rest of the layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnailImageView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_videocam_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Thisisaverylongnameforavideofilethatforsureexceedsthetextviewsize"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnailImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/thumbnailImageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="2018-01-01"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/thumbnailImageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnailImageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/durationTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Duration"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/dateTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dateTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hasTrackingTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"

        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/durationTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.42" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried initializing `checkBox` before calling `super` and verifying that it is not `null` at that point?

Comment: `super()` always has to be called first. I tried to initialize ckeckBox on declaration, but I assume that is also called after super().
`findViewById()` returns null at that point, so i can only assume i can not get a reference to the button in this part of the program...?

Comment: What if you put a null check in, so `if(checkBox != null) checkBox.setChecked(checked);`? Or find CheckBox beforehand and pass it in?

Comment: Of course I can check for null, but that misses the whole point, because I WANT the `CheckBox::setChecked()` to be called. Retrieving a valid `CheckBox` object was part of my question in the first place.

Comment: I understand, just wondering if super() is calling it during setup where it'd be ok to skip that call as long as it gets set up properly later.

Comment: I tried out your suggestion. So `super()` does not call this method. It only gets called when it is supposed to, and during that time the `checkBox` is still initialized with null.

Comment: If you just want to have a CheckBox with the layout, you can add it directly by code. In init(), try `checkBox = new CheckBox(context); this.addView(checkBox);` and remove `checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);`Hope that helps!